# android save-Lazy List HashMap

Tags: android

I want to Serialize the Hash-Map of Default Lazy-list code and store it in a file on device..

Actually I want the images to be locally stored,,,,

As,my project contain a lot's of images to be used from server.... Please provide a way or code for modified lazy-list that stores the Hash-Map in a file.. As next time when app restart the Image-loader class must have that object so,,that image is not downloaded from server...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a variable named `cacheDir` and change `getBitmap()` method of `ImageLoader` class to this below one

```
private Bitmap getBitmap(String urlString)
{
    String filename = String.valueOf(urlString.substring(urlString.lastIndexOf("/") + 1));
    File f = new File(cacheDir, filename);
    try
    {
        if(!f.exists())
        {
            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            InputStream is = new URL(urlString).openStream();
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
            Globals.CopyStream(is, os);
            os.close();
            bitmap = decodeFile(f);
            return bitmap;
        }
        else
        {               
            Bitmap bitmap = decodeFile(f);
            return bitmap;
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        BitmapDrawable mDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.placeholder);
        return mDrawable.getBitmap();
    }
}
```

Comment: Globals.CopyStream(is, os); In this Globals cannot be resolved in code..  Would this code be effective when app restarts I want images to be saved and used if they are already shown earlier

Comment: hiiii,,, thx It was my mistake in implementing your code,,,,  It's working now......